# Jquery - Setting a select list option by id

Tags: jquery

I feel like this should not be this complicated, but I'm sure I'm missing something trivial.
Thanks for anyone that can help!

XSL:

```
<select id="mySelectList">
  <option id="1" description="Blue" />
  <option id="2" description="Black" />
  <option id="3" description="Green" />
</select>
```

JS:

```
$("#mySelectList option[id='1']").attr("selected", "selected");
```

EDIT:  Fixed my select per Nick's response.

Answer (score 25):

A `<select>` should look like:

```
<select id="mySelectList">
```

Or if you literally want the element and that's XML, remove the `#` for an [element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/), like this:

```
$("mySelectList option[id='1']").attr("selected", "selected");
```

Comment: Ack sorry, Nick.  I missed the select on my tag when I wrote it into my question.  It should indeed be:
<select id="mySelectList">
.
</select>

The jquery command I used (and you reiterated) have not been working for me.  Can't figure out why.

Comment: @SethPlante - are you running it inside a `document.ready` handler?

Comment: Yup.  See my comment above to the other poster.  Switching over to using value="1" instead of id="1" is working, but I'm going to keep trying to figure out what's up with the problem using id.

Comment: @SethPlante - Why *not* use value as it was designed?  Then it would just be : `$("#mySelectList").val(1);` :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code should select what you want.

Are you sure that you want your `<option>` to be without a text value ?

Maybe you want

```
<select id="mySelectList"> 
  <option id="1" description="Blue">Blue</option>
  <option id="2" description="Black">Black</option>
  <option id="3" description="Green">Green</option>
</select>
```

Also keep in mind that you select the first item, which is selected by default.

example at http://www.jsfiddle.net/Zfx3e/

Answer (score 0):

In HTML4, ID attributes must begin with a letter, not a number ([see the specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name)).  E.g.

```
<select id="mySelectList">
  <option id="opt1" description="Blue" />
  <option id="opt2" description="Black" />
  <option id="opt3" description="Green" />
</select>
```

So you could do

```
$('#mySelectList option[id="opt1"]);
```

Comment: They can't begin with a number *in HTML4*, should be specific about that from here on out, given HTML5's adoption.

Comment: Thanks for the response, lonesomeday.  I made the suggested changes but still does not work.  Not sure what it hates about trying to use ID, but when I switched to using "value" instead it worked.  Unfortunately that requires some back-end Java fixes to switch from "id" to "value."  Any other ideas?

Comment: @SethPlante Try using the `id` selector instead of an attribute selector: `$('#mySelectList option#opt1')`